# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 at NSManagedObject(entity:

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a very big project in Swift (ios app) where I need to do a lot of modification and access to coreData at different places in different threads. I first faced a lot of problem of accessing the data while another thread were changing it so i restructured my project like this :

```
class dataManager {
    var bool : isAvailable

    func func1 ()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            if(isAvailable)
            {
                self.isAvailable = false
                doStuff1
                self.isAvailable = true
            }
            else
            {
                sleep(1)
                func1()
            }
        }
    }

    func func2 ()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            if(isAvailable)
            {
                self.isAvailable = false
                doStuff2
                self.isAvailable = true
            }
            else
            {
                sleep(1)
                func2()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the real project there is much more than 2 functions. And then my viewControllers in the main thread call the functions when necessary. So basically the functions wait for the access to coreData to be available so they can read or write without any problem. The functions are called every 2 min or so so it should not be a problem to wait for the other to be done before to execute. This seems to work pretty fine, it runs fine but after some times, it will crash and give me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 . It crashes at this line :

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: self.namesEntry[i], in: managedContext)!
let event = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext) //crashes here
```

The variable managedContext is created once at the creation of the class :

```
    managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

and then accessed by every function.

I've read a lot of article about this error but they all say that the data is trying to access something that have been deleted so I don't understand how is this possible? considering there is only 1 function working ( I've checked with prints to be sure and indeed only one function is being accessed) Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably not related but *wait*ing for something and *sleep*ing is always a very bad choice.

Comment: it was to avoid going on loop to man times, i thought that after a second the other process would probably be over

Comment: Your console will display a log that has more detail in regards to the error you are encountering. Utilize the log when possible because it will aid you in debugging your code.

Comment: What is `dostuff1` and `dostuff2` ?

Comment: do stuff are functions that are potentialy long and do either reading or writting data into coreData like in a loop create entities and insert them into managedContext.  then save the context at the end of the loop .

Comment: I ended up using different context for each function. I am not sure if this is the best practice but it resolved my problem.
 I  started each function with : 

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            
            let threadContext : NSManagedObjectContext =  NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
            threadContext.parent = self.managedContext;

and then use this context  .  Is it a valid practice?? thank you